# Spring JPA Repository - Keep data on server restart

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-boot

I'm currently trying to learn how to use Spring Boot and have a problem I'm not sure how to solve.

I've followed the [Accessing Data with JPA](http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/) guide and everything works fine. However, if I restart the server, then all the data that was saved is completely lost. Is there any way to keep the data in the repository/database so that if I shut down the application and start it again, all the previously saved data is still accessible?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: serialize the data on exit to a file and deserialize on load to bring application back to last state.

Comment: When you use a database, data serialization is the worst thing you could do. The problem here is just the missing understanding, how the database used in the examples works.

Answer (score 12):

All examples use an embedded database with in memory persistence, which means, the data is only stored as long as the process is running. Just switch to a regular database like MySQL or use H2 with a file based storage url, which is also permanently saved on your disk. For the latter, just add the following property to your application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/${path/to/your/db/file}
```

and replace `${path/to/your/db/file}` with the path where you want to store the database (note, the folder you configure here will be created, if it doesn't exist).

Comment: The example doesn't have an application.properties file, where would I add it and how would I implement it? And I have no idea how to change switch the database used, I'll have to do some studying and figure that out.

Comment: The application.properties can be in many places, consult the Spring Boot documentation for that: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files
I would place it under src/main/resources as default configuration file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 7):

If you want to keep your data on server restart then add the following property into the `application.properties` file:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Answer (score 6):

It seems that your `application.properties` file has below setting. Remove or comment it.

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

Comment: I set `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` to `none` in my properties files and manage schema via `schema.sql` in my src/main/resources folder. e.g.

`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = none`

Answer (score 3):

I have used this in my project where I want to keep data after server Restart.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/data/testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;
```

This will store data in a file. You can check [H2 Features](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html) for more details.